# Soma Condicional em cada linha R?

Tags: r

Eu estou tentando criar uma função que pega o valor fixo de uma linha df[1,3] e subtrai ela pelo valor de uma outra linha de um dataframe df[,1] e o resultado dessa subtração ser também subtraído pela linha de baixo da mesma coluna df[,1](e assim sucessivamente)e ao mesmo tempo rodar um ifelse que se o valor resultante dessas substrações for inferior a um certo valor, some o resultado das subtrações por um outro objetoB.
Alguém tem ideia de como faço isso?

meu script:

```
objetoA<- 100

valor <- 20

objetoB<-40
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c(10,10,10,10,10)
df <- data.frame(b,a)
df[1,3]<-100
funcao<- function(x) {df[1,3] - df[,1] + (ifelse(df[1,3] - df[,1] <= valor,objetoB+df[1,3] - df[,1],0))}

print((last(map(objetoA, funcao))))
```

Dessa forma que está no Script subtrai o df[1,3]por cada linha separadamente, linha por linha, e me volta o resultado de cada linha como se eu pegasse a coluna e fizesse isso: df[1,3]- df[,1] apenas ou seja não subtrai o resultado das substrações pela linha debaixo..

Porém eu quero que ele pegue o valor da primeira subtração e subtraia pela linha de baixo e assim por diante enquanto verifica a condição do ifelse... Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

O resultado nesse caso seria apenas 100-10-10-10-10-10=50

Comment: `df` só tem duas colunas, `b` e `a`. `df[1,3]` não existe. Quando faz `df[1,3]<-100` imediatamente antes de definir a função, está a criar uma nova coluna com todos os outros valores `NA`. Pode postar a saída esperada desse código com os dados da pergunta?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Rui, quando eu dou View(df) após fazer df[1,3]<-100, eu vejo que um valor de 100 foi criado pra primeira linha da terceira coluna. Eu gostaria que a saida pra esse codigo fosse 50 pois a condicao do ifelse não vai ser acionada porque o resultado das subtrações não chega a menor ou igual ao valor 20. A conta que a funcao faria seria 100-10-10-10-10-10= 50

Answer (score 0):

Quando você estiver lidando com alguma estratégia de repetição, vale a pena verificar se não é um laço (loop) que você está procurando. No *snippet* abaixo utilizei um **for**.

```
objetoA<- 100
valor <- 20
objetoB<-40
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c(10,10,10,10,10)
df <- data.frame(b,a)
df[1,3]<-100

> df
   b a  V3
1 10 1 100
2 10 2  NA
3 10 3  NA
4 10 4  NA
5 10 5  NA

for (i in seq(nrow(df))) {
  res <- (df[1,3] - df[i, 1])
  if (res < valor) {
    res + objetoB
  }
}

> res
[1] 90
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, mas me veio uma duvida no seu codigo, ele subtraiu o 100 por 10 apenas uma vez... a minha intencao era pegar o resultado dessa subtracao e subtrair pela linha de baixo ate a condicao do ifelse ser verdadeira para somar com outro objeto, e depois disso continuar subtraindo. No df em questão o res deveria resultar em 50 pois o 100 seria subtraido por 10 cinco vezes e a condicao ifelse não seria verdadeira em nenhum momento nesse df

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a seguinte função faz o que a pergunta pede, com a diferença que o resultado final é `60` e não `50`, uma vez que se o primeiro valor de `df[1, 3]` deve ser mantido então a função só faz 4 subtrações e não 5.

```
funcao2 <- function(x, val, obj){
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(x))[-1]){
    x[i, 3] <- x[i - 1, 3] - x[i, 'b']
    if(x[i, 3] <= val) x[i, 3] <- x[i, 3] + obj
  }
  x
}

funcao2(df, valor, objetoB)
#   b a  V3
#1 10 1 100
#2 10 2  90
#3 10 3  80
#4 10 4  70
#5 10 5  60
```

Answer (score -1):

Consegui fazer pra quem quiser o codigo:

```
objetoA <- 100
valor <- 20
objetoB <- 40

a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(10,10,10,10,10)

df <- data.frame(b,a)
df[1,3] <- 100

subtrair <- append(df[1,3], df$b)

resultado <- reduce(subtrair, function(a,b) {a-b})

while (resultado <= valor) { 
  resultado <- resultado + valor
}

print(resultado)  

>50
```